# QTcpSocket: Server response delay after hours of communication

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qt5, qtcpsocket

I know some similar questions may have been asked already, but the answers to those I found did not solve my problem.

I am runnning a QTcpSocket to recieve data over network from a client. The client asks for measurement values all 50ms and server responds. The respons from server comes right away.
After running of 4h, the response from server comes with a delay of about 400ms and after days it is delayed for several seconds.
When i restart the server, the response comes right away again. When the delay is there and i restart the client and connect again to the socket, the same delay is there.

I do not know any buffer i can clear or something like this, since i do read the sended data, which should clear the buffer. Has anyone an idea, what causes this delay?

On server i read:

```
    QTcpSocket* clientConnection = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    QString data="";

    if (clientConnection->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
        return;

    QByteArray tmp=clientConnection->readAll();

//  Also tried:
//  QByteArray tmp;
//  while (clientConnection->bytesAvailable())
//      tmp.append(clientConnection->readAll());


    for(int i=0;i<tmp.size();i++)           
        data += tmp.at(i);
```

In data is asked for a value, i read that value, write it in data and answer with:

```
    QByteArray block;
    if(!data.endsWith("\n"))
        data = data+"\n";
    block=data.toLatin1();
    clientConnection->write(block);
```

On client side i read the answer:

```
    if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
       return;

    QByteArray tmp;
    while(tcpSocket->bytesAvailable())
        tmp.append(tcpSocket->readAll()); 

    for(int i=0;i<tmp.size();i++)               
        data += tmp.at(i);
```

and ask again:

```
    block = command.toLatin1();
    if(socket)
    {
//      Already tried this:
//      socket->write(block,block.size());
//      socket->flush();
//      socket->waitForReadyRead(30000);

        socket->write(block);
    }
```

I already tryed with 
clientConnection->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);  //Disable Nagle Algorithm

But nothing works. 
Anyone got an idea, what the problem is here?
Any tips are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: This call `data = data+"\n";` appends a line character to the data. It looks suspicious. What if you try to comment it out and measure the delay again? Can you log the data you exchange between server and client to see, whether it changes over time?

Comment: Yes i have logged the data. Client sends data string with "Voltage1\n". Server recieves this and answers the value. When the delay rises, client sends "Voltage1\n" and in wireshark i see, that server only acknowledge and no response. Then after some sends from client, server recieves "Voltage1\nVoltage1\nVoltage1\n" and answers all three requests in one call.

Comment: Aha. That means the system, in some cases, accumulates the data and it needs more time to process it. I also noticed, that you use loops to read the data. They may block your server and it is not able to process the coming requests during the processing of the current one.

Comment: If this is the case why is it fine in the beginning and the delay rises with time. If i stop send on client side when the delay is big and start after some minutes again. the delay is present instant. Like there is a full buffer, but i do not know about a buffer i can clear. Any idea?

Comment: I think it's a snowball effect. Try to increase the time between requests from 50ms to 100ms, for example. But this theory doesn't answer your question. Maybe the problem is in the code you didn't mention. You might try to profile your server application during the delayed responses.

Comment: I already tryed increasing to 100ms. With this, the delay rises more slowly. So its better, but not the solution. In the code in betwee are some short sleeps yes, this might delay the response a bit, but what causes the added delay over time. Shouldnt be there some kind of clear (reset the snowball)?